# Regex circle-dependency

Tags: java, regex, dependencies

I have got a problem while designing my scripting language.

We have expressions:

```
1 + 2

x

a := b + c

... etc
```

function call can contain expressions:

```
myfunc(1 + 2 + 3, b)
```

and expression can contain function calls:

```
a := myfunc(1, 2) * x
```

and function call can contain function call (as a parameter):

```
myfunc(f(x), g(x))
```

they can be all combined together:

```
a := calc(f(x) + g(x), 1) + y
```

My problem is **how to represent these relations using `java.util.regex.Pattern`**. If I declare `Pattern EXPRESSION` first, then it uses `Pattern FUNC_CALL` while not declared yet. The same thing occurs when declaring FUNC_CALL first, since it uses EXPRESSION too.

Code snippet:

```
/**
* Expression is any positive number of either (number, spaces, operator, function call, or identifier).
*/
public static final Pattern EXPRESSION = Pattern.compile("(\\s*(\\s+|" + NUMBER.pattern()
        + "|" + OPERATOR.pattern() + "|" + FUNC_CALL.pattern() + "|" // Error : FUNC_CALL is not initialized
        + IDENTIFIER.pattern() + ")+)");
/**
* Function call is an identifier, followed by "(",
* followed by arguments which are any non-negative number of 
* either (identifier, comma, or spaces), followed by ")"
*/
public static final Pattern FUNC_CALL = Pattern.compile(IDENTIFIER.pattern()
        + "\\s*\\(" + "(" + EXPRESSION.pattern() + "|\\s+|\\,)*\\)");
```

Answer (score 3):

You are asking too much from regular expressions. What you want is impossible. Normally regular expressions are used in a much smaller way when parsing expressions, such as recognizing legal function names, operators, and values. In order to parse a full expression, you may want to try a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) because that is the simplest technique.

If you must include infix operators then that will increase the complexity of your parser quite a bit. You will want to learn about [operator-precedence parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser). It's not hard to write a nice parser once you understand how the parser works. You can write even an operator precedence parser in a few lines of code, but figuring out the algorithm can be tricky. If you intend to do it yourself your best way will be to look up resources to help you on the web, such as: [Parsing expressions by precedence climbing](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/08/02/parsing-expressions-by-precedence-climbing/), and [Parsing Expressions by Recursive Descent](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm). I can't do better than tutorials like those.

The natural alternative to doing it yourself is to use a parser generator that does everything for you. Here is a list of many options: [Comparison of parser generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators).

Comment: I need at least the idea of how to implement this parser on my recursive dependency.